# CSS Flexbox with Equal Sized Child Element

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm doing one of the project for FreeCodeCamp's certificate and I'm having trouble getting the FlexBox's child elements to have equal size (height and width).

I have tried multiple use of Flex-Grow, Shrink, etc. But it seems like because of the length of the contents inside the element, they are not equally sized.

My Codepen: https://codepen.io/jyjang703/pen/PooeGxv

Basically, I want the third and 4th box of the FlexBox to be same size...
Any help would be appreciated!

```
<header>
    <h1>Self-Happiness Survery</h1>
    <h4>For anyone with regrets, griefs, and looking for changes...</h4>
</header>

<main>
  <div>
  <fieldset class="PersonInfo">
    <form action="">
      <label>First Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="First Name">
      <br>
      <br>
      <label>Last Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="Last Name">
      <br>
      <br>
      <label>Email:</label>
      <input type="text" name="Email">
      <br>
      <br>
      <label>Number:</label>
      <input type="tel" name="Number" minlength="1" maxlength="10">
      <br>
      <br>
    </form>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset class="PersonInfo_2">
    <form action="">
      <label>Age:</label>
      <input type="text" name="First Name">
      <br>
      <br>
      <label>Sex:</label>
      <select>
        <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
        <option value="Male">Male</option>
        <option value="Female">Female</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <br>
      <label>Occupation:</label>
      <input type="text" name="Email">
      <br>
      <br>
      <label>Current Martial Status:</label>
        <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male"> Male
        <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female"> Female
      <br>
      <br>
    </form>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset class="Checkbox_1">
    <form action="">
      <label>What is causing your inner pain?</label>
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Pain"> Breakup
      <input type="checkbox" name="Pain"> Current Job
      <input type="checkbox" name="Pain"> Friendship
      <input type="checkbox" name="Pain"> Family Issue
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Pain"> Future
      <input type="checkbox" name="Pain"> Self Confidence
      <input type="checkbox" name="Pain"> Loneliness
      <input type="checkbox" name="Pain"> Financial Stability
    </form>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset class="Checkbox_2">
    <form action="">
      <label>What is causing your inner pain?</label>
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Pain"> Breakup
      <input type="checkbox" name="Pain"> Current Job
      <input type="checkbox" name="Pain"> Friendship
      <input type="checkbox" name="Pain"> Family Issue
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Pain"> Future
      <input type="checkbox" name="Pain"> Self Confidence
      <input type="checkbox" name="Pain"> Loneliness
      <input type="checkbox" name="Pain"> Financial Stability
    </form>
  </fieldset>
  </div>

  <fieldset class="Additional_Information">
    <h3>Please provide any additional information</h3>
    <form action="">
      <textarea rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Additional Life Storeis Here...">
      </textarea>
    </form>
  </fieldset>
</main>
```

Below is CSS:

```
body{
  background-color: #f3e9fc;
}

header{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

div{
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

label{
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: left; /*Change to right here if you want it close to the inputs*/
}

.Additional_Information{
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `flex-basis:0` and `flex-grow:1` on the child element of flexbox.

[Basis](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-basis.asp) is like minimum size. Then [flex-grow](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-grow.asp) gives the size equally to all elements.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.PersonInfo,.Checkbox_1,.PersonInfo_2,.Checkbox_2
{
  width:25%;
}
```

I added this at the end of your css in codepen which made it all the same size

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this what you want? 1st & 2nd fieldsets are the same size and 3rd & 4th are the same size.

```css
fieldset {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want equal width for the child element, You need to set the width.

```
div {
      width: 80%;
      display: flex;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
.PersonInfo,.Checkbox_1,.PersonInfo_2,.Checkbox_2 {
      flex-basis: 25%;
    }
```

Comment: If you want equal width for the child element, You need to set the width.